Equivalent impedance response seen by two places is different
Why is this circuit's impedance seen from Vout is different if seen from the emitter of Q2 plus the Resistor R1 in series.
Solution-> Seen from the emitter with R1 in series:

While doing the small signal model with an Vx and Ix added to calculate Rout from the Vout gives me:
r_pi2 - Small signal model Resistor pi of Q2.
gm2 - gm of Q2.
Rout = (R1  -  r_pi2  -  gm2 * r_pi2 * R1)/(1-r_pi2*gm2)
Q1's Rout seen from Vout is going to be an open circuit that will be in parallel with the Vout seen upwards which we can neglect using the parallel formula.

Exercise 5.46 a) "Fundamental of microeletronics" by Behzad Razavi
EDIT: simplifying gives me something similar to the solution's Rout but I still have a signal '-' instead of '+'. First equation is taken from looping the right side (vx, R1, current source) second one left side (vs, R1, r_pi2).


Your solution is wrong. The Rout is as it was shown by the book solution Rout = (R1 +( 1/gm2||1/rpi2))|| RoutQ1. Try to show us your small signal model and calculation so we can see where the mistake you made.

if I do the small signal model with R1 connected to Q2's emitter and a voltage to be able to do the Rout that should give the book's Rout? I know in the theory he does Rout seen from the emitter upwards and then he adds R1

If you meant this circuit https://i.sstatic.net/yRmuWw0w.png Then yes, you should get the same result as was given in the book.

I will edit with my calculation

Notice that Ic = Vpi * gm and Vpi will be negative in this case.  Ic = gm*-Vpi

why? To be fair I usually try to not put a voltage drop around a current source and when I put it its always the opposite way but I just kinda memorized because it works. I don't know the reason why though.

Because we have a base at AC GND and positive AC voltage at the emitter. "Normally" emitter current will flow out (leave) the emitter terminal.  But now we have "negative" Vpi voltage, thus Ic will flow in the opposite direction "into" emitter.

Adding vx and Ix we are opposing the normal flow of the emitter?

Exacly, we are opposing the normal flow.

Don't find it super intuitive but i got it! thank you!

We have this circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
From KVL we have:
$$V_X = R_1 I_X + (I_C + I_X)r_{\pi}  $$
$$V_X = R_1 I_X + ((-V_{\pi} \times g_m) + I_X)r_{\pi}  $$
Notice that now \$V_{\pi}\$ is negative. Because we have the base terminal at the GND potential.
$$V_X = R_1 I_X + ((-V_{\pi} \times g_m) + I_X)r_{\pi}  $$
$$V_X = R_1 I_X + r_{\pi}(I_x - V_{\pi}\: g_m)  $$
$$V_X = R_1 I_X + r_{\pi}(I_x - g_m (V_X - I_X R_1)) $$
$$V_X = R_1 I_X + r_{\pi}I_x + I_X R_1 r_{\pi} g_m - r_{\pi} g_m V_X $$
$$V_X = I_X( R_1 + r_{\pi} + R_1 r_{\pi} g_m ) - r_{\pi} g_m V_X $$
$$V_X = \frac{I_X( R_1 + r_{\pi} + R_1 r_{\pi} g_m )}{ 1 + r_{\pi} g_m}$$
And finally:
$$ R_{OUT} = \frac{V_X}{I_X} = \frac{R_1 + r_{\pi} + R_1 g_m r_{\pi} }{ 1 + g_m r_{\pi}} = \frac{R_1 (1 +  g_m r_{\pi}) + r_{\pi}}{1 + g_m r_{\pi}}$$
Additional I know that \$r_{\pi}g_m = \beta\$
Therefore:
$$R_{OUT} =  \frac{R_1 (1 +  \beta) + r_{\pi}}{1 + \beta} = R_1 + \frac{ r_{\pi}}{1 + \beta} = R_1 + r_e $$
Also you can try to prove to yourself that \$\frac{1}{g_m}||r_{\pi}\$ is equal to \$r_e\$.
Confusion about the meaning of re and rπ
